# What is the difference between scheduled and tumbling trigger?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm exploring the Azure Data factory scheduled and tumbling trigger.

In both cases suppose I choose the 1 hour recurrence interval, then the pipeline runs every hour.

When should we use scheduled vs tumbling trigger?

Comment: hey @variable, any other query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tumbling window triggers have a self-dependency property which is not available with Schedule triggers. If the consecutive pipeline runs depend on each other, the self-dependency property can be used. Other significant differences between these triggers, including the self-dependency property are mentioned in the following Microsoft Q&A link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/207405/when-to-use-tumbling-window-type-trigger.html

Similar thread:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194846/what-is-the-behavior-of-adf-schedule-triggers-when-a-schedule-starts-before-the#:~:text=The%20trigger%20used%20has%20a,not%20available%20with%20Schedule%20triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194846/what-is-the-behavior-of-adf-schedule-triggers-when-a-schedule-starts-before-the#:%7E:text=The%20trigger%20used%20has%20a,not%20available%20with%20Schedule%20triggers).

Comment: If you add an example then it will be more understandable

Comment: Hey @variable, the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194846/what-is-the-behavior-of-adf-schedule-triggers-when-a-schedule-starts-before-the#:~:text=The%20trigger%20used%20has%20a,not%20available%20with%20Schedule%20triggers. provides everything with detailed example. Do you still need another example

Comment: As per that example of tumbling window, how does etl refer to previous run when the previous run is still running?

Answer (score 0):

Tumbling window has a self-dependency property i.e. we can't process to next window until previous one is successfully completed. This property is not there in schedule trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Tumbling window is different than schedule trigger in the sense as, you can add a dependency of self which would help to avoid parallel runs if you intent to.
If you don't want your pipeline to run its parallel instance if the schedule arrives early or before finishing the previous run, then tumbling window would be a go to option.
[Add your dependency here within definition of your trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DimbF.png)